# R throw away rows on multiple conditions

Tags: r, filter, dataframe, subset

I have a question about filtering in my dataset. My dataset look like this:

```
      PROJECT       FREQ
1       <NA>         NA
2       <NA>         NA
3       FSHD 0.01282051
4       <NA>         NA
5       <NA>         NA
6  GROEI,CMS 0.02564103
7       <NA>         NA
8      GROEI 0.00000132
9       <NA>         NA
10  NMD,BRCA 0.03846154
```

Here is my problem: I want to throw away all the rows that haven't in the PROJECT field: GROEI and in the FREQ field: bigger than 0.01.

I thought about something like this, but this isn't the way..

```
a1<-a[!(a$PROJECT != "GROEI" & a$FREQINHDB >= 0.02),]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to match on a partial string, you can use `grepl` to match a regular expression with your data:

```
na.omit(a[!grepl("GROEI", a$PROJECT), ])
    n  PROJECT       FREQ
3   3     FSHD 0.01282051
10 10 NMD,BRCA 0.03846154
```

Comment: Dear Andrie, is this the right solution? a[!(grepl("GROEI", a$PROJECT) == FALSE & aFREQ > 0.04),]

Comment: @Lisann That looks feasible. You don't need the `== FALSE`, and test whether you need `&&` instead of `&`. Do you get the correct results with your code?